# Redux with Polymer and dom-repeat

Tags: redux, polymer, dom-repeat

I have a problem with nested `dom-repeat`'s and changes deep in arrays.
Using redux I change properties on an array which has a structure like this:

```
[{some: 'value', members: [{ id: 13, hobbies: [{id: 33, name:'hobbyname'}]}]}]
```

When for example a hobby is deleted from a member, I see when I have an observer method on this property and `console.log` the value of the array that it really changed, the hobby is gone.

The DOM does however not change. The structure of that is something like:

```
<template id="teamslist" is="dom-repeat" items="[[teams]]">
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[item.members]]" as="member">
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[member.hobbies]]" as="hobby">
```

I tried notifying the `dom-repeat` like this but it does not help:

```
this.notifyPath('teams[0].members[0].hobbies.length');
```

Calling `render()` on the `dom-repeat` (top-level) does not seem to help either:

```
this.$.idfordomrepeat.render()
```

What am I doing wrong here..?

Comment: [[]] is just one way, only supports downward flow. Use {{}} for teams template to support both downward and upward flow.

Comment: Another potential issue could be that your state is not properly updated?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the path segments should be separated by dots. Look [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/model-data).

Try `this.notifyPath('teams.0.members.0.hobbies');`

Does that work?

Comment: fixed it by fixing my way of handling state in Redux, and it wasn't needed now but still good to know this, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the end it was a problem with the Redux state not being updated where I thought it was (Redux noob...)
When that was fixed the notifyPath wasn't needed, and nor was the render() call.

Comment: Hey, I have the same issue as you. Could you elaborate a little on where you didn't update the state correctly? thx a lot

Comment: no sorry, but installing the redux tools in chrome and just debugging your reducer should show you that much I think.